# Error converting MySQL TIMESTAMP to DATETIME

Tags: mysql

I have a table (example_table_1) which has a timestamp column declared as follows:

```
`ts1` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This MySQL statement generates a syntax error:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table_2 AS
SELECT DATETIME(ts1)
FROM example_table_1
```

How do I get my second table to have the TIMESTAMP data as a DATETIME column?

Comment: The specific error message that you're receiving would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
create table example_table_2 as
select cast(ts1 as datetime) as ts1
from example_table_1
```